# Using colormap with bokeh scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, bokeh, colormap

In `matplotlib` the [scatterplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) offers the possibility of using the color of a plot to indicate value or magnitude like this plot:

[image]

For `bokeh`, similar [examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/color_scatter.html) seem to manually generate the rgb colors, which makes it difficult to produce plots with color scaled by magnitude, esp. wrt. diverging colormaps.

Is it possible to have similar functionality in `bokeh`, or to use `matplotlib` colormaps to set the color?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's easy enough to just use `matplotlib`'s colormaps directly. For example, the following uses `viridis` in `bokeh`'s example (note that I'm using a jupyter notebook):

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
import matplotlib as mpl

output_notebook()

N = 4000
x = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
y = np.random.random(size=N) * 100
radii = np.random.random(size=N) * 1.5
colors = [
    "#%02x%02x%02x" % (int(r), int(g), int(b)) for r, g, b, _ in 255*mpl.cm.viridis(mpl.colors.Normalize()(radii))
]

p = figure()

p.scatter(x, y, radius=radii,
          fill_color=colors, fill_alpha=0.6,
          line_color=None)

show(p)
```

Essentially, for any matplotlib colormap in `cm`, initializing it with an array of values will return an array with each value replaced by [r,g,b,a] values in the range [0,1]. Note that this assumes all the values are between 0 and 1 as well; here I use matplot.colors.Normalize to ensure this.

Answer (score 6):

Another option if you want to use a field name, is to use a LinearColorMapper:

```
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Magma256', low=min(radii), high=max(radii))

p.scatter(x,y,color={'field': 'radii', 'transform': color_mapper})
```